# Añadir recordatorio a una nueva entrada de calendario

Tags: android, android-studio

Muy buenas. Verán, estoy creando en Android un formulario que el usuario debe rellenar. Entre los diferentes campos, hay uno para seleccionar una fecha, y otro para seleccionar una hora.

Una vez que el formulario es validado, lanzo un Intent para crear una nueva entrada en el calendario. Es decir, que se abra el calendario, específicamente, el formulario que crea una nueva entrada para el calendario, y le relleno al usuario la mayoría de los datos (fecha, hora, descripción...). El usuario sólo tiene que pulsar en Guardar para que la nueva entrada quede fijada en el calendario.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Ejemplo titulo");
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startDateMillis);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endDateMillis);
intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, false);
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Ejemplo descripción"));
startActivity(intent);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> (En verde los campos que he conseguido que aparezcan completados en el Intent, en rojo el que me gustaría editar).

Con los extras puedo rellenar casi cualquier campo del formulario que se abre en el calendario (lo que he marcado en verde). El problema con el que me encuentro es que no consigo de ninguna manera añadir notificaciones (Reminders en Android). La idea sería que se añadan dos notificaciones, una hora antes del evento y un día antes del evento (la parte marcada en rojo). ¿Alguien sabe cómo se podría hacer?

Nota: Se trata de un Intent, no de un acceso a la base de datos del calendario.